# unset session variable in zend view

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element, zend-session

I ll reframe my question based on some research I have done?

I need to store lot of errors separately like $_SESSION['client_error'],$_SESSION['state_error'] etc.
According to zend documentation do I have to store it like this for each error?

```
$client_error = new Zend_Session_Namespace(''client_error);
$state_error = new Zend_Session_Namespace('state_erro'); and so on?
```

This is my code in the controller.
I am storing it as
    $this->view->state_error_message=$state_error;

After I echo $this->state_error in the view I want to unset it.

Ok here are few more things I tried:
In the controller in policyInfoAction:

```
    session_start();
$error_message = new Zend_Session_Namespace('error_message');
$error_message="TEST";
$this->view->error_message=$error_message;
$this->_redirect('/pdp/client-info/');
```

In the view in client-info:

```
session_start();
<?php echo $this->error_message; ?>
```

This returns nothing.

Ok this is my updated code:

```
    public function clientInfoAction()
        {

            $errors = new Zend_Session_Namespace('errors');
            // get the error arrays
            $client_errors = (isset($errors->client_error)) ? $errors->client_error : array();
            $state_errors  = (isset($errors->state_error)) ? $errors->state_error : array();
            unset($errors->client_error, $errors->state_error); // delete from the session

            // assign the values to the view
            $this->view->client_errors = $client_errors;
            $this->view->state_errors  = $state_errors;
}


    public function policyInfoAction()
    {

         if (count($arrErrors) > 0)
         {

            // The error array had something in it. There was an error.
            $strError="";

            foreach ($arrErrors as $error)
            {
            $strError="";
            $errors->client_error = array();
            $errors->state_error  = array();


            foreach ($arrErrors as $error)
            {
                $strError .= $error;
                // to add errors to each type:
                $errors->client_error['client_error'] = $strError;
                $errors->client_error[] = $strError;
                $this->_redirect('/pdp/client-info/');


            }
               }
}
```

When i echo $this->client_errors I get 'Array'

Comment: So far this make no sense. What are you trying to do...Exactly? Are you trying to validate a form and alert the user? Are you trying to save error messages? Where is your data coming from? Please provide some detail so we have chance to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some advice and suggestions that can hopefully get you on the right track.

First, when using `Zend_Session` and/or `Zend_Session_Namespace`, you never want to use PHP's `session_start()` function<sup>[1](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html#zend.session.advanced_usage.starting_a_session)</sup>.  If you start a session with `session_start()`, and then try to use `Zend_Session`, it will throw an exception that another session already exists.

Therefore, remove all `session_start()` calls from your Zend Framework application.

Second, you mentioned you had a lot of messages you need to store, so this may not be the right thing for you, but see the [FlashMessenger](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger) action helper.  This allows you to set a message in a controller, and then access it on the next page request.  The messages only live for one page hop, so after the next page load, they are deleted.  You can store many messages with the FlashMessenger, but your access to them is not very controlled.  You could use multiple flash messengers each in differen namespaces also.

To solve your problem in particular, you could just do something like this:

```
// in controller that is validating
$errors = new Zend_Session_Namespace('errors');
$errors->client_error = array();
$errors->state_error  = array();

// to add errors to each type:
$errors->client_error['some_error'] = 'You had some error, please try again.';
$errors->client_error['other_error'] = 'Other error occurred.';
$errors->client_error[] = 'Other error, not using a named key';

$errors->state_error[] = MY_STATE_PARSING_0;
```

What is happening here is we are getting a session namespace called `errors` creating new properties for `client_error` and `state_error` that are both arrays.  You don't technically have to use multiple Zend_Session_Namespaces.

Then to clear the messages on the next page load, you can do this:

```
// from controller again, on the next page load
$errors = new Zend_Session_Namespace('errors');

// get the error arrays
$client_errors = (isset($errors->client_error)) ? $errors->client_error : array();
$state_errors  = (isset($errors->state_error)) ? $errors->state_error : array();

unset($errors->client_error, $errors->state_error); // delete from the session

// assign the values to the view
$this->view->client_errors = $client_errors;
$this->view->state_errors  = $state_errors;
```

See also the source code for `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger` which can give you some idea on managing data in session namespaces.

Comment: I actually want to send the error messages to the previous page which has a form. But i guess ur above method could work. Thanks..i ll try

Comment: Is the form using Zend_Form?  That method sends to any page depending on what page they are directed to after the form.

Comment: I am little confused. so I have a form in /pdp/client-info/ which goes to action ='pdp/policy-info' on submit.If there are errors then I set the session arrays as mentioned above in policyInfo action. Do I unset  it in clientInfo action? Sorry for my confusion even though you provided a great explanation.

Comment: Ok i updated my code above.I get nothing even though $strError has some values from post variable.

Comment: From the code you posted it looks like you are missing `$errors = new Zend_Session_Namespace('errors');` in the `policyInfoAction()`  Did you make sure to get the session there as well?

Comment: Yes, $errors = new Zend_Session_Namespace('errors'); is set in policyInfoAction().

Comment: never mind. It's working now. thanks @drew010!
@RockyFord.I shall look into your method too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you or not but here is the code for a controller that just takes an id from a form a gathers data based on that id an assigns that data to the session (to be used throughout the module) and then unsets that data when appropriate. and Never leaves the Index page.

```
<?php

class Admin_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    //zend_session_namespace('location')
    protected $_session;

    /**
     *set the layout from default to admin for this controller
     */
    public function preDispatch() {

        $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('admin');
    }

    /**
     *initiaize the flashmessenger and assign the _session property
     */
    public function init() {

        if ($this->_helper->FlashMessenger->hasMessages()) {
            $this->view->messages = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger->getMessages();
        }
        //set the session namespace to property for easier access
        $this->_session  = new Zend_Session_Namespace('location');

    }

    /**
     *Set the Station and gather data to be set in the session namespace for use
     * in the rest of the module
     */
    public function indexAction() {

        //get form and pass to view
        $form = new Admin_Form_Station();
        $form->setAction('/admin/index');
        $form->setName('setStation');

        $this->view->station = $this->_session->stationName;
        $this->view->stationComment = $this->_session->stationComment;
        $this->view->form = $form;

        try {
            //get form values from request object
            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

                if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {

                    $data = (object)$form->getValues();

                    //set session variable 'station'
                    $this->_session->station = $data->station;

                    $station = new Application_Model_DbTable_Station();
                    $currentStation = $station->getStation($this->_session->station);
                    $this->_session->stationName    = $currentStation->station;
                    $this->_session->stationComment = $currentStation->comment;

                    //assign array() of stations to session namespace
                    $stations = $station->fetchAllStation();
                    $this->_session->stations = $stations;

                    //assign array() of bidlocations to session namespace
                    $bidLocation  = new Application_Model_DbTable_BidLocation();
                    $bidLocations = $bidLocation->fetchAllBidLocation($this->_stationId);
                    $this->_session->bidLocations = $bidLocations;

                    $this->_redirect($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
                }
            }
        } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {

            $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
        }
    }

    /**
     *Unset Session values and redirect to the index action
     */
    public function changestationAction() {

        Zend_Session::namespaceGet('location');
        Zend_Session::namespaceUnset('location');

        $this->getHelper('Redirector')->gotoSimple('index');
    }

}
```

just to be complete i start the session in the bootstrap. On the theory that if I need it great if not no harm.

```
 protected function _initsession() {
        //start session
        Zend_Session::start();
    }
```

this is all the view is:

```
<?php if (!$this->station): ?>
    <div class="span-5 prepend-2">
        <?php echo $this->form ?>
    </div>
    <div class="span-10 prepend-2 last">
        <p style="font-size: 2em">Please select the Station you wish to perform Administration actions on.</p>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="span-19 last">
        <?php echo $this->render('_station.phtml') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```